# Share Status on facebook visible to limited users

Tags: java, android, json, facebook-graph-api, rest

I am using following method to share status on facebook.

```
if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", msg);
        try {
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
            System.out.println(response);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Posted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        login();
    }
```

I checked graph api that has a parameter **allow = "profileid1,profileid2,profileid3"** but it is embedded in an object . Now i can't find that how can add this parameter in bundle .

This is how graph api explorer shows result .

```
    "privacy": {
    "description": "Friends; Except: Artemas Ali, Artemas Ali",
    "value": "CUSTOM",
    "friends": "ALL_FRIENDS",
    "networks": "",
    "allow": "",
    "deny": "1000036022153129,1000017534323389"
  },
```

Comment: what do you mean by "but it is embedded in an object"?

Comment: Read the question again or check graph api me/feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done that by simply adding values to JSON object and then convert into string to pass values to API.

```
 if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", msg);
        if(!customUsers.equals("")){
        JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();

        try {
               obj.put("value", "CUSTOM");
               obj.put("friends", "ALL_FRIENDS");
               try{
                   obj.put("deny", customUsers);   
               }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
                   Log.d(customUsers, ex.toString());
               }

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        parameters.putString("privacy", obj.toString());
        }
        try {
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
            System.out.println(response);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Posted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```